# Javascript Regexp not returning global results

Tags: javascript, regex, global

It's my understanding that all three of these lines below should return an ARRAY with 2 results in it. Yet RegExp will only return 1 result no matter how many times the regex repeats in the string.

Can some one explain why? And perhaps suggest how I can get RegExp to give me global results?

```
//INTPUT: 
    console.log(new RegExp("New York", "gi").exec("New York New York")); 

//OUTPUT: 
["New York"]

//INTPUT: 
    console.log(new RegExp(/New York/gi).exec("New York New York"));

//OUTPUT: 
["New York"]

//INTPUT: 
    console.log("New York New York".match(/New York/gi));

//OUTPUT:
["New York", "New York"]
```

Comment: now what really intrigues me is that if you try `(' New York New York ').match(/ New York /gi)` it will bring just 1 result (as kinda expected) and I can't think of a better way to go around this (when otherwise needed) [other than iterating over it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328875/javascript-regex-to-remove-all-numbers-with-specific-lenght-or-do-a-persistent)! :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

your third example is the best way to get the array of matches.

RegExp.exec actually remembers its position, and returns the next result on subsequent calls:

```
>>> var v = /new york/gi
>>> v.exec("NEW YORK new york")
["NEW YORK"]
>>> v.exec("NEW YORK new york")
["new york"]
>>> v.exec("NEW YORK new york")
null
```

Comment: you could leverage this to build an aray yourself, but it's easier to just call string.match

Comment: I have an array of keywords that I'm trying to get a count of the number of occurrences in a string. what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 13):

This is expected, exec() returns a single match but provides more info about the match than match(). If you just want all the matches, use match(). From [JavaScript:  The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996):

> Recall that match() returns an array
>   of matches when passed a global
>   regular expresion. exec(), by
>   contrast, always returns a single
>   match and provides complete
>   information about that match. When
>   exec() is called on a regular
>   epression that has the g flag, it sets
>   the lastIndex property of the matched
>   substring. When exec() is invoked a
>   second time for the same regular
>   expression, it begins its search at
>   the character position indicated by
>   the lastIndex property.